# Access ${request.remoteUser} in java

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

I am able to access `${request.remoteUser}` in my `xhtml`-file: eg. Logged in as `${request.remoteUser}`.

But how do I get access to `${request.remoteUser}` in my BackingBean.java.

Comment: What is a java file? A Servlet class? A JSF controller bean? Your desktop app?

Comment: The java file is the BackingBean connected to my xhtml-page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a JSF backing bean you can access it via:

```
HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServeltRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()
request.getRemoteUser();
```

See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29).